# You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly 550001

Tags: .net, paypal

Had a system all up and running fine, but was left alone for a few months now when i came back to test it I'm getting this error on the Live site

PayPal You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly 550001

The account used to send payment is the same as the one in the API details, i've checked the api signature etc, and the sender email is being set

It's working fine in sandbox, just not live

Comment: Has the app ever worked in Live? If yes, contact support www.paypal.com/mts. If no, you need to submit your application via apps.paypal.com

Comment: Anyone else got any ideas, is it paypal or me? Raised with support nearly a week ago, getting no response at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I think I'm onto something here.

Maybe you could try the same:

1. Go to https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications/manage
2. Click "View History" below the one App causing trouble
3. Find a reply from PayPal, something like:

> [...] Please send contact information, business website URL and a brief
>   business summary to compliance@paypal.com and aquire the preapproval
>   before resubmit the app for approval. Otherwise, please consider to
>   change your business model and implement a marketplace model which is
>   using PayPal chained payment API with you as the secondary receiver
>   and the seller as the primary receiver. [...]
>
> Follow their instructions and keep your fingers crossed that they will grant the required privileges