# PayPal Adaptive payments error You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a simple app that sends payments. The app works fine in sandbox. Live classic app app ID is already approved (shows as "Approved Automatically"), but when I enter my live credentials it returns the error "You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly"

Sending XML to endpoint `https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay`:

I'm sending it using my live API key, and live account credentials:

- applicationId = my live app ID (already approved)
- X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID = my live API user ID (blah_api1.mysite.com)
- X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD = my live API password
- X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE = my live API sig
- X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION = 1.1.0
- X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID = live app id (e.g. APP-5F976659LV9322736)
- X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT = XML
- X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT = XML

Sending payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PayRequest xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
<requestEnvelope>
  <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
  <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
</requestEnvelope>
<clientDetails>
  <applicationId>APP-5F976659LV9322736</applicationId>
  <partnerName>MyName</partnerName>
</clientDetails>
<actionType>PAY</actionType>
<cancelUrl>https://mysite.com</cancelUrl>
<returnUrl>https://mysite.com</returnUrl>
<currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
<feesPayer>EACHRECEIVER</feesPayer>
<memo>blah blah</memo>
<receiverList>
  <receiver>
  <amount>6.66</amount>
  <email>personimpaying@gmail.com</email>
  </receiver>
</receiverList>
<senderEmail>me@gmail.com</senderEmail>
<trackingId>f166b253-063e-4e24-9fd0-519ccddfffeb</trackingId>
</PayRequest>
```

Reply:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns3:FaultMessage xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
<responseEnvelope>
  <timestamp>2014-01-13T20:49:46.191-08:00</timestamp>
  <ack>Failure</ack>
  <correlationId>5924cfcacbf00</correlationId>
  <build>7935900</build>
</responseEnvelope>
<error><errorId>550001</errorId>
<domain>PLATFORM</domain>
<subdomain>Application</subdomain>
<severity>Error</severity>
<category>Application</category>
<message>You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly</message>
</error>
</ns3:FaultMessage>
```

I tried both my registered emails in the "senderEmail" field - both have same problem.

I've seen a few people coming up against this issue, but no resolution. Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT - I've also tried explicit payments, however when I try to ExecutePayment on the payment I get the following error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns3:FaultMessage xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">

<responseEnvelope>
 <timestamp>2014-02-02T19:34:44.256-08:00</timestamp>
 <ack>Failure</ack>
 <correlationId>abcdefg</correlationId>
 <build>7935900</build>
</responseEnvelope>

<error>
 <errorId>550001</errorId>
 <domain>PLATFORM</domain>
 <subdomain>Application</subdomain>
 <severity>Error</severity>
 <category>Application</category>
 <message>User is not allowed to perform this action</message>
</error>

</ns3:FaultMessage>
```

Comment: FWIW already opened a ticket with PayPal support weeks ago.. no reply still.

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919670/you-do-not-have-permission-to-execute-this-payment-implicitly-550001

Comment: @JSuar yes - but in my case the app is already approved. the only thing in the history shows "The application has been approved."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I think I found the answer. In the API application, I ticked the checkbox for "Send Money", but there is another option that I missed "Implicit Payments". I'm going to try again with the new option ticked.

Comment: Confirmed with PayPal that this is indeed the case (yes - it took 1 month for them to answer the support ticket, but they did in the end).

Comment: for me it is not the case. even by ticked the checkbox you said, it didn't worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329755/implicit-paypal-payment-pay-you-do-not-have-permission-to-execute-this-payme

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but for me the problem was the account I was using in app is the same as the owner of the app. There was no bug in the app, it worked as I wanted, but just not with my credentials.

I fixed my issue by creating a new PayPal account to use my app with.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If my API is linked to account ABC, I can't make implicit payments from account ABC?  That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. I have no idea why. It makes no sense. I was getting this error "You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly" with the account linked to my app then I tried with a different account and it worked fine. Tried again with the linked app account and error. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: So I can implicitly send money from anyone else's account, as long as I don't control it? In my case I just decided to not send implicitly, now I setup the payment and mail myself the link so I can approve it. But I'm not really understanding Paypal's logic on this concept?

Comment: Yeah I don't get it either. Seems dumb. At the very least a correct error message would be nice.