# How to pay my website users with Paypal API (masspay alternative)

Tags: php, paypal

I have been trying almost every API method Paypal provides to pay users of my website (using PHP).

-Masspay is blocked for every "small" account.

-Adaptive Payments just let me to pay max. 10 users and requires manual confirmation.

Is there any way to pay users without my interaction using Paypal API calls? What should be my next attempt since masspay and adaptive payments does not seem to work?

I just want to send money to arround 30 different users daily with a scheduled job.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself :)

It seems the only way to do what I need is Adaptive **Implicit** Payments

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

You need to provide a **$payRequest->senderEmail** address (same email than your app adress) when calling Adaptive API to avoid manual confirmation of transaction.

Comment: The next problem you will face when doing this is detailed here. We are still working on how to solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106523/paypal-adaptive-payments-error-you-do-not-have-permission-to-execute-this-paymen